# Angular multiple instances of same directive, scope is not isolated , same scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the directive multiple times on the page like

```
$scope.stylusright[0] = 330;

var appendHtml = $compile('<directive-history rightstylus="{{stylusright[0]}}"></directive-history>')($scope);

$element.append(appendHtml);

$scope.stylusright[1] = 660;

var appendHtml = $compile('<directive-history rightstylus="{{stylusright[1]}}"></directive-history>')($scope);

$element.append(appendHtml);
```

My directive looks like

```
angular.module('mymodule').directive('directiveHistory', function ($compile)
{
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: true,
transclude: true,
templateUrl: 'directive.history.html',
scope: {
rightstylus: "@",
}, 
...
```

My Problem is, when the same directive is added to the same page multiple times, their scope becomes same. when I change $scope.stylusright[1] in 2st directive it also makes changes in all other directives.

Comment: That's the behavior. If you do not want to change this, just make a copy of the value you want to reference. angular.copy($scope.stylusright[1]), otherwise you are making a reference and does not matter if your directive has isolate scope every time you change $scope.stylusright[1] value, will change your directive value.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive code don't looks wrong, (only you have duplicate scope key).

take a look on this plunker, is something similar of what you want to do with isolate scope directives 
    [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/jdTBISOyMlLa4UUXA65b/)

hope it helps